# roots of a several variable for the equation $y-3x^2-y^3=0$

Tags: several-complex-variables

How can I get the roots of the next equation?

$$y-3x^2-y^3=0$$

I just dont get the same answer than my teacher:

$$x = \frac {- \sqrt2}{3(3^{1/4})}, y = \frac{-2}{\sqrt3}$$

Comment: That equation has many roots

Comment: There had to be something else in the question. Maybe it was a system of two equations, not just this one equation by itself?

Comment: $x=0$, $y=0$, is just as valid.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Graph of the function in question]

Any point on the graph will satisfy the equation. You might wish to verify that your teacher's solution lies on the graph by squaring the $x$, cubing the $y$ and taking the designated combination.